# How to display user profile picutre from sql database stored as blob data in python flask

Tags: python, database, flask

im creating a website in python flask where i want to display a photo for loggin users.
My database looks like this:

[image]

And i dont know how decode ProfilePicutre data and then display it in flask(diffrent for everyuser, like twitter profile picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're storing your `ProfilePicture` file in some sort of binary (displayed in hex) column. Since you haven't mentioned any tools used to query the database (SqlAlchemy or similar) I can't be specific in the solution but,
try retrieving the data ans inspect it to figure out if it's returned in bytes, string or something else. After retrieving this data, try converting it into base64. For example purposes, consider that the `ProfilePicture` is retrieved in bytes and converted with the following line:

```
base64_image = base64.encodebytes(row.ProfilePicture).hex()
```

Having the image encoded in base64 you can render it in your HTML with the following line,
if you're using server side rendered HTML (with jinja or some similar library):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_image }}" alt="{{ row.Username }} Profile Picture" />
```

In case you have a REST API, return it and use your JS library to render the image tag just like shown above.

Good luck.